# NaTType' object has no attribute 'dt' error when comparing null and not null

Tags: python, pandas

Stack overflow!

I am trying to create a column using the defined function below.
The goal is to count the number of days between dates based on the condition of 3 columns.
However I am getting an error: *NaTType' object has no attribute 'dt'*

```
def onhire_counter(df):
    """returns col, num of days (int) item is onhire"""
    today = datetime.today() 
    
    if df['DisCompleteDate'] and df['OffHire'] is pd.NaT:
        return (today - df['ErCompleteDate']).dt.days
    
    elif df['DisCompleteDate'] is not pd.NaT and df['OffHire'] is pd.NaT:
        return (df['DisCompleteDate'] - df['ErCompleteDate']).dt.days
    
    elif df['DisCompleteDate'] is pd.NaT and df['OffHire'] is not pd.NaT:
        return (df['OffHire'] - df['ErCompleteDate']).dt.days
    
    else:
        return 0

df_hire['days_onhire'] = df_hire.apply(onhire_counter, axis = 1)
```

I have also tried `.isnull` & `.notnull`

Thanks for your help.. You are awesome!

Answer (score 0):

Your issue seems like you have a `NaT` in your `ErCompleteDate` column. Any datetime or timestamp subtracted by a NaT will produce a NaT. An if statement at the start of the function can catch this out.

```
if df["ErCompleteDate"] is pd.NaT: return 0 # Or None depending on your case
```